# Two random variables converge in distribution and difference is decreasing in $L^2$. What can we say about them?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I am well aware that the convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability. However, is there any way to improve on this result? In particular, I am curious about whether for nice random variables we have the following?

Suppose that $E[|v_n-x_n|]>E[|x_{n+1}-v_{n+1}|]$ is decreasing and suppose that $v_n \to f$ and $x_n \to f$ in distribution. Can we show that $v_n, x_n$ converge to the same limit (assuming the limit exists) in probability, $L^2$ or a.s.?

Comment: The expression $v_n \to x_n$ doesn't make sense. Do you mean $v_n - x_n \to 0$?

Comment: Uhm, yeah sorry, sloppy notation for saying that they converge to the same limit. The reason I wrote it like that is that in my particular application $v_n=v$ does not really depend on $n$.